# What is the meaning behind Poe's "The Assignation"?

Tags: short-stories, edgar-allan-poe

Has anyone read and analyzed Poe's "The Assignation"? I read it and have a preliminary understanding of it but failed to perceive greater nuances by far.

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Is there any specific aspect of this work you'd like to see analysed? As it stands, your question may be just a bit too broad, as well as bordering on asking for recommendations.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I think this question is OK, along the lines of [this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1955/17) or [this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2178/17). It's acceptable to ask for an analysis/meaning of a whole *short* story.

Comment: @Randal'Thor shameless plugs much? :P I see your point, though.